# Converting AES decryption from php to c#

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

I'm attempting to convert some working php code to c# in order to do aes decryption.

Working PHP code:

```
function convert_from_hex($h) {
    $r="";
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($h); $i+=2) 
        if ((isset($h[$i])) && (isset($h[$i+1]))) 
            $r.=chr(hexdec($h[$i].$h[$i+1]));

    return $r;
}

function decryptAES($crypt_text, $key) {

    $crypt_text=convert_from_hex($crypt_text);                                              // convert from hex

    $iv = substr($crypt_text, 0, 16);                                                       // extract iv
    $crypt_text = substr($crypt_text, 16);                                                  // extract iv

    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');                 // decrypt
    @mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $package = @mdecrypt_generic($td, $crypt_text);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);                                                             // close encryption
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    $padqty=ord($package[strlen($package)-1]);                                              // remove padding

    return substr($package, 0, strlen($package)-$padqty);
}
```

Broken C# Code:

```
public string test()
        {
            string data = ConvertHex("149B56B7240DCFBE75B7B8B9452121B0E202A18286D4E8108C52DBB2149D820B980FFC7157470B9573AA660B2FAAB158E321023922191BCEA5D6E1376ABE6474");

            string iv = data.Substring(0, 16);
            string toDecrypt = data.Substring(16);

            return AESEncryption.DecryptString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toDecrypt), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("C728DF944B666652"), Encoding.Default.GetBytes(iv));
        }

static public string DecryptString(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            // Declare the string used to hold 
            // the decrypted text. 
            string plaintext = null;

            byte[] binaryDecryptedData;

            // Create an Aes object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
                aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);


                // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream srDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            var buffer = new byte[1024];
                            var read = csDecrypt.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            while (read > 0)
                            {
                                srDecrypt.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                                read = csDecrypt.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }
                            csDecrypt.Flush();
                            binaryDecryptedData = srDecrypt.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in binaryDecryptedData)
                sb.Append((char)b);
            plaintext = sb.ToString();

            return plaintext;
        }

        public string ConvertHex(String hexString)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                string hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);

                sb.Append((char)Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16));
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

The correct output of the PHP code is:
Fail (1) Not a valid Request or Command.

The output of the C# code is:
²H,-§±uH¤¥±BÃrY¡|¡JJÑ¾à`ªx"äommand

I'm guessing that I have some sort of encoding issue, although I've tried many different options without success.  Both code snippets are running on a windows box, so I believe the default encoding is windows-1252.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Replacement for ConvertHex which fixed my issues (thanks to owlstead's help)

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the `ConvertHex` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the first 16 bytes of string data instead of 16 bytes of binary data. This is what is causing the main issue. You need first to [convert hex to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) and then strip off the first 16 bytes to use as IV. Your `ConvertHex` method (not shown) is broken, it should return a byte array. The fact that your decrypted plaintext does end correctly with `"ommand"` clearly indicates a problem with the IV value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try as you suggested for the IV and see what happens.

Comment: I believe based on how PHP removes the padding that it is actually PKCS7.  The encryption for the input string was done by a windows program and not php.

Comment: Whoops, you are right, should have recognized the unpadding, sorry about that - will remove.